# How to write code for tracking rich media banner ads? like numbers of impressions, clicks on particular buttons etc

Tags: javascript, php, tracking

Actually, I am working on an ad platform for the advertiser, so I need to show rich media banner ads reports as well. Like the number of impressions, clicks received, how many times videos played in ads(if any video there with ad), number of clicks on particular buttons/elements.

Please guide me. All the suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: [ask] // This is way too broad of a question for this site. We can help you with specific programming problems, if you ask specific questions. “Please guide me” is anything but that though. _You_ need to do some initial work yourself here first of all.

Answer (score 0):

What You are asking is very broad. Anyway, am gonna try for you.

First You may need for example to create different Table that will hold those information's in your database. A quick look at the table might look like below

```
// create table to hold users/clickers info
create table user(id int primary key auto_increment,username varchar(30));

// lets insert into user table
insert into user(id,username) values(101,'Nancy');

//create table ad_tracking
    create table Ad_Tracking(id int(11) primary key auto_increment,likes int(11), views int(11),video_clicks int(11) ad_info text);

// Create ad_like table
create table Ad_like(id int(11) primary key auto_increment,likes int(11), ad_id int(11),user_id int(11));

// Create ad_viewers table
create table Ad_view(id int(11) primary key auto_increment,views int(11), ad_id int(11),user_id int(11));



// Create video_click table
create table Ad_video_click(id int(11) primary key auto_increment,video_click int(11), ad_id int(11),user_id int(11));
```

So lets assume you have inserted values into it as per below

```
insert into Ad_Tracking(id,ad_info) values(1,'My first Ad');
insert into Ad_Tracking(id,ad_info) values(2,'My second Ad');
```

**Using Like(or video_clicks or view counts as a case studty)**

Ideally query to add like count,
You will need the **ad_id** of the ad_tracking, the **user_id** of the user etc. before then you will need to run sql queries to check if the user that is about to click video,likes etc already done that.

So your insert will look like

```
insert into ad_like(like,ad_id,user_id) values(1,1,101);
```

You can now code along with php or whatever language you want.
I guess you get the hint now...